# How can a child class access the parent's pointer to a property?

Tags: objective-c, inheritance, properties, overriding

In a child class, I need to override a property getter. The child will need to compare the parent's value and decide whether to return it or return something else.

In the following example, I have a *Person* that has a *Heart*. Both *Person* and *Heart* derive from *Unit*. A *Person*'s modification date is the latter of his entire body and all his organs (in this example he only has one organ - a heart). The problem is the autogenerated pointer `_dateModified` is undeclared for the child class.

```
@interface Unit
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSDate* dateModified;
@end

@interface UnitHeart : Unit
@end

@interface UnitPerson : Unit
@property (nonatomic, strong) UnitHeart* heart;
@end

@implemenentation UnitPerson

- (NSDate*)dateModified
{
    if (_dateModified.timeIntervalSince1970 > self.heart.timeIntervalSince1970) {
        return _dateModified;
    } else {
        return self.heart.dateModified;
    }
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe what you are after is:

```
- (NSDate*)dateModified
{
    if ([super dateModified].timeIntervalSince1970 > self.heart.dateModified.timeIntervalSince1970) {
        return [super dateModified];
    } else {
        return self.heart.dateModified;
    }
}
```